# What is the easiest way to draw a horizontal bar in Android?

Tags: android, graphics, canvas

Without using any outside APIs, how do I draw a simple green horizontal bar to depict a percentage? (Full being 100%)

One way I thought of was using a SeekBar but I'm not sure how to customize the height, colors, etc of it.

Is there a formula I could use to draw a rectangle on a canvas or something that would use the desired scale that I need?

For example, if I have a refrigerator that can fit 38 items, a full bar would render when there was 38 items present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) See the documentation.

Sample code.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0" />
```

Note this `style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"` It makes the Progress a horizontal bar instead of the spinner you were talking about. U can set the color and drawable by using `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/mydrawable"`

Comment: @PetrakovichJ did u see the progressbar??

Comment: Hmm, I have but for some reason I thought it was only the circular loading animation.  Would I have to do something to the drawable to make it a certain color/size?

Answer (score 1):

I originally thought you meant drawing a horizontal line via XML, which is easy. 
However, you can add a View, or TextView or whatever method (that has an XML counterpart) in your code, and set it in a loop.

Comment: I never thought of this!  I like this idea as well